# Check if any object in array has value true?

Tags: javascript

I have an array that looks like this simplified:

```
[{one: false,two: 'cat'},{one: true, two: 'dog'},{one: false, two: 'ball'}]
```

I want to check if any of the one, values are true. The solution I can think of is something like

```
var truthness;
array.forEach(function (element, i, array) {
 if(element.one){
    truthness = true
    break;
 }
}

if(truthness){
  //code
}else{
  //other code
}
```

is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Not really, you'd have to iterate either way.

Comment: Libraries like jQuery and Underscore.js have functions for this, but if you're not using them then this is the way to do it.

Comment: Here's a neater way to write it -> http://jsfiddle.net/LS9kH/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Arrays have a method [`.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), which returns `true` if the callback returns `true` for any element in the array, or `false` if it returns `false` for every element in the array.

```
var truthness = array.some(function(element) {
    return element.one;
});
```

Comment: I like that much better than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing would work perfectly one small optimization might be to use a while loop.

```
var i = array.length;
while (i--)
    if (array[i].one)
        break;

if (i >= 0) {
    //truhness
} else {
    //other code
}
```

it basically does what you did just with possibly a little faster loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
var arr = [{one: false,two: 'cat'},{one: true, two: 'dog'},{one: false, two: 'ball'}];

var truth = arr.some(function(elem) {
    return elem.one;
});
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

> `some` executes the callback function once for each element present in the array until it finds one where callback returns a true value. If such an element is found, some immediately returns true. Otherwise, some returns false. callback is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values; it is not invoked for indexes which have been deleted or which have never been assigned values.

Answer (score 0):

The same as you are doing but maybe a little neater (YMMV), you could use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if any of the values are true. The beauty of `some` is:

> If such an element is found, some immediately returns true.

If you're catering for older browsers there's a polyfill at the bottom of that page.

```
var data = [{one: false,two: 'cat'},{one: true, two: 'dog'},{one: false, two: 'ball'}];
var data2 = [{one: false,two: 'cat'},{one: false, two: 'dog'},{one: false, two: 'ball'}];

function oneIsTrue(data) {
  return data.some(function (el) {
    return el.one;
  });
}

oneIsTrue(data); // true
oneIsTrue(data2); // false
```